# Dúvida ao gerar um arquivo .doc com C#

Tags: c#, .net

O método abaixo faz o download do documento que é gerado dinamicamente, porém quando o arquivo é aberto mostra uma opção de conversão de arquivo, 
deixando marcado por default o item *Unicode(UTF-8)*.

O que fazer para não mostrar essa mensagem?

```
    public static void gerarRelatorioAtoDoc(string texto)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/msword";

        String strNomeArquiv = "RelAtoGerado" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().ToString() + ".doc";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + strNomeArquiv);

        StringBuilder strHTMLContent = new StringBuilder();
        strHTMLContent.Append(texto);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(strHTMLContent);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    }
```

Comment: O que tem em texto? Aliás, qual o impedimento de usar uma biblioteca que gere um documento formatado?

Comment: eu passo um parametro pro metodo, texto pode ser qualquer coisa, no caso ai se trata de um comunicado vindo de um <asp:TextBox>

Comment: e qual seria a biblioteca em questão, que gera o documento?

Comment: [Falo de alguma coisa tipo isso aqui](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/660478/Csharp-Create-and-Manipulate-Word-Documents-Progra). Seu esquema funciona, mas vejo ele mais como um improviso. Fica mais difícil formatar o documento desta forma.

Comment: Certo vou pegar essa biblioteca e implementar aqui, pra ver como se comporta.

Comment: ele tem uma procedimento que salva em um diretorio específico, tanto que nao consigo apontar pra um diretório existente em meu drive; mas pelo que parece ser é bem simples e útil. vou testar em casa. mesmo assim muito obrigado man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com a ajuda de [cigano-morrison-mendez](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/2999/cigano-morrison-mendez) e usando a biblioteca [DocX v1.0.0.14](https://github.com/WordDocX/DocX) solucionei o problema da seguinte maneira:

```
    public static void gerarRelatorioAtoDoc(string texto)
    {
        string fileName = @"C:\Users\seu-nome\DocXExample.docx";
        var doc = DocX.Create(fileName, DocumentTypes.Document);
        doc.InsertParagraph(texto);
        doc.Save();
        Process.Start("WINWORD.EXE", fileName);
    }
```

O parâmetro texto pode ser qualquer coisa, no caso acima ele recebe o conteúdo de um `Textbox`.